# Часть контента пропадает на телефонах

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте!
Проблема такая, часть контента пропадает на телефонах, на всех в разных места обрезается. Поменял 2 хостинга, ничего не помогло, как исправить это?

Тестировал на Meizu M5, Asus Zenfone Go

Заранее благодарен.

Ссылка на сайт (может поможет)
1. http://victory-factory.ru/dd/
2. http://smart-kids-shop.ru/dd/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5264/191482)

Answer (score -1):

уберите на мобилке для блока .blur-without-header фильтры

```
/* -webkit-filter: blur(0); */
/* filter: blur(0)
```

Скрин после удаления фильтров
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_e8DUn99fcEM2RHRUxJWExoZFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Проблему не решило

Comment: вы на каком домене убрали? посмотрю

Comment: http://smart-kids-shop.ru/dd/

Comment: у меня контен отображается нормально, Android 7.1.1 OnePlus5, попробуйте через хром подебажить на мобилке, возможно ещё какие-то спецефические фильтры перекрывают контент.

Здесь инфа как подключить debug для мобильников
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

скрин https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_e8DUn99fcEM2RHRUxJWExoZFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: У меня вообще ничего не поменялось

Comment: @user234223 кэш перед проверкой чистили?

Comment: @andreymal Да, вообще безрезультатно

Comment: @andreymal Ах да, актуально в браузере Chrome на мобильных, во встроенных, кажется, такой проблемы нет

Comment: Ну, во всяком случае на моих телефонах

Comment: тоесть у вас в Chrome ошибка осталась? какая версия?

Comment: @KamilMagomedov
На обоих устройствах последняя, а версия андроид 4.4.2 и 6.0

Comment: @KamilMagomedov Есть какие-то идеи?

Comment: @user234223 у меня устройст нет с такими опциями, единственный вариант подебажить через ваши мобильники, я выше кидал вам описание как это делать(т.к. устройство нужно физически).

Comment: @KamilMagomedov Я случайно ткнул на пустое место (Где не прогружается, попал на инпут, и контент появился, потом с инпута убрал и снова исчез...

Comment: А на Meizu вообще само появилось просто

Comment: ну на Meizu видимо Кеш застрял